# Log_sum_exp of a convex function is not dcp compliant?

Tags: r, convex-optimization, cvxr

I have a convex function f(b):

```
f(b) = log(pi) - lambda * log( t(r) %*% b)
```

dim(pi) = (n,1), lambda is a scalar constant, dim(r) = (n,n)

b is the parameter, dim(b) = (n,1)

The call to

```
is_convex(f) 
is_dcp(f)
```

both return TRUE.

However, I don’t understand why the following returns FALSE:

```
is_dcp(log_sum_exp(f))
```

As far as I understand, log_sum_exp of a convex function is convex?

I noticed that both

```
is_convex(f)
```

and

```
is_concave(f)
```

return FALSE.

So it seems like CVRX is unable to deduce the convexity of log_sum_exp(f)?

Any help would be appreciated

(I use CVRX ver 0.99 package in R3.5)

Comment: I haven't used CVRX myself, but is it possible that it's unaware of the sign of your variable lambda? It being positive or negative will obviously affect convexity

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed in [CVXR v0.99-5](https://github.com/anqif/CVXR/releases/tag/v0.99-5).